# How to know if a pendrive can be safety removed?

Tags: usb, usb-drive

Imagine that you copy a large file to a pendrive, and then you press the USB release button in nautilus. A warning window appears telling not to release the USB because data is being written. This window fades out in some seconds. Then you do not look at the screen for 15 seconds and look again to the screen.

How do you know if the warning window saying that you can safety release the USB has appeared and faded out so you can take your USB or it is still writing data in the USB and you have to wait?

In both cases the release button in nautilus has disappeared.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When I click safely remove and I no longer see the drive icon on the side menu, I figure the drive has been safely removed, never lost any data assuming this.

I'm quite sure if the drive is still running the icon remains in place and you get a "the volume is busy" warning.

This is confirmed by:

https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/files-removedrive.html